How to get started on Levi Flat Hypersurfaces
Levi Flat Hypersurfaces is a potential topic for my Master's project. What are the pre requisites to get into this?
Books, papers, lecture notes etc. are welcome as suggestions.
I know some algebraic geometry (ch1 of Hartshorne and a little bit of sheaves) and am familiar with basic differential geometry (except deRham cohomology).
Would really appreciate it if someone could provide with a roadmap(s).
Thanks!
